# DataTables: Disable header click sorting, still allow manual sorting

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) and would like to have sorting done with dropdown menus rather than with clicking on the table headers. I have the dropdown menu sorting functionality in place, but I can't figure out how to disable the table header sorting without also disabling the dropdown menu sorting. How can I disable *just* the table header sorting?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bHKNQ/)

## JavaScript

```
function update_sort() {
    var sort1 = $('#sort1').val();
    var sort2 = $('#sort2').val();
    var sort3 = $('#sort3').val();

    var sorting = [[sort1, 'asc']];

    if (sort2) {
        sorting.push([sort2, 'asc']);
    }

    if (sort3) {
        sorting.push([sort3, 'asc']);
    }

    var table_obj = $('table').dataTable();

    table_obj.fnDestroy();

    table_obj.dataTable({
        'bPaginate': false,
        'bFilter': false,
        'bInfo': false,
        'aaSortingFixed': sorting
    });
}

update_sort();

$('p select').change(function() {
    update_sort();
});
```

## HTML

```
<p>
    Sort By:

    <select id="sort1">
        <option value="0">Column 1</option>
        <option value="1">Column 2</option>
        <option value="2">Column 3</option>
    </select>

    Then By:

    <select id="sort2">
        <option value="">---------</option>
        <option value="0">Column 1</option>
        <option value="1">Column 2</option>
        <option value="2">Column 3</option>
    </select>

    Then By:

    <select id="sort3">
        <option value="">---------</option>
        <option value="0">Column 1</option>
        <option value="1">Column 2</option>
        <option value="2">Column 3</option>
    </select>
</p>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>B</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: if can't find a way in the API...can set table wrapper position:relative, and append an absolute position div that sits over the header

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can unbind the click handler:

```
table_obj.find("th").off("click.DT");
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/bHKNQ/1](http://jsfiddle.net/bHKNQ/1/)

Comment: Thanks. Your answer gave me a tip regarding a related problem that i am trying to solve. The difference is i need to switch clicking on and off. I tried table_obj.find("th").on("click.DT"); but it did't work. Any idea why is that ?? Please see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407171/jquery-data-table-sorting-and-filtering-records